# Marketing Cloud (Exacttarget) Custom Installed Package not visible in the App Exchange menu on some accounts

Tags: marketing-cloud, appexchange, app

I have 2 user accounts in the same organization.

I have created an installed package with the "Marketing Cloud Component" that gives access to login, redirect, logout urls.

In the app exchange menu, there is a link to the following page:

https://mc.s10.exacttarget.com/cloud/#app/

But it is only accessible to the account that added the "Marketing Cloud" component, no other user account can see the menu option, nor visit that link.

I know this is an unpublished app, but I want to know if the other user accounts can be able to view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow other users to view the app you need to:

Administration (top right) > Installed Packages > Click your app > LICENSES > License to everyone in org

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the app per business unit. Once the app is installed for that business unit, users in that business unit will see the link under the AppExchange menu, provided that they have the permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the response iManage! Can you provide a bit more context on how to configure the app per business unit? This is not a published app on the app exchange as well.